# Loading external Scripts with JS based on current Subdomain

Tags: javascript, if-statement, subdomain

I would like to load those external scripts below with JS based on the current subdomain someone is on. Could you help me writing the function doing this? I was looking a lot for a solution on this but could not find one.

order.test.de

```
<script src="https://test.com/banner.js" data-key="820ed7d9-95be-460f-be32-cf569f640fb4"></script>
```

order.test.ch

```
<script src="https://test.com/banner.js" data-key="6e4718c5-df40-4f94-83cc-16e8b105e6b9"></script>
```

order.test.com

```
<script src="https://test.com/banner.js" data-key="5e593e1d-dc8c-482f-a0b8-b5a82b3cad04"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could inspect the url String if it contains ".de/.com" and load the corresponding Link using a if question

Comment: Exactly. Any Idea how to do it?